# Calculate duration and group continual timestamps in logging table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to calculate durations for a log table that checks every two minutes and if there are any alerts it will enter them. The over simplified table format is as follows:

```
RuleID   TimeStamp  
1        2013-04-10 08:40
1        2013-04-10 08:42
1        2013-04-10 08:44
2        2013-04-10 08:40
2        2013-04-10 08:42
1        2013-04-10 09:40
1        2013-04-10 09:42
```

The result I am looking for is as follows:

```
RuleID   EarliestTimeStamp   LatestTimeStamp   DurationInMins
1        2013-04-10 08:40    2013-04-10 08:44  4
2        2013-04-10 08:40    2013-04-10 08:42  2
1        2013-04-10 09:40    2013-04-10 09:42  2
```

As you can see Rules can be logged multiple times throughout and if there is a break of more than two minutes then it is counted as a new event and is a new result entry.

I can provide more detail if required, unfortunately, I cannot provide my dataset to work with.

Comment: How large is your dataset. Millions of records, thousands, or hundreds?

Comment: I have tried t-clausen.dk's solution but the logging table has 100,000s of records and continues to grow so the query takes forever to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the nice brain exercise for the Friday afternoon. Here is what I have come up with:

```
;WITH s AS
(SELECT t1.RuleID, t1.TimeStamp AS StartTime from Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON
t1.RuleID = t2.RuleID and dateadd(minute, 2, t2.TimeStamp) = t1.TimeStamp
WHERE t2.TimeStamp IS NULL)
,e AS
(SELECT t1.RuleID, t1.TimeStamp AS EndTime from Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON
t1.RuleID = t2.RuleID and dateadd(minute, -2, t2.TimeStamp) = t1.TimeStamp
WHERE t2.TimeStamp IS NULL)
SELECT s.RuleID, s.StartTime, e1.EndTime, datediff(minute, s.StartTime, e1.EndTime) AS DiffInMins FROM s INNER JOIN e AS e1
ON s.RuleID = e1.RuleID AND s.StartTime < e1.EndTime
AND e1.EndTime = (SELECT MIN(EndTime) FROM e AS e2 WHERE e2.RuleID = e1.RuleID AND s.StartTime < e2.EndTime)
```

Here is the result:

```
| RULEID |                    STARTTIME |                      ENDTIME | DIFFINMINS |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 | April, 10 2013 08:40:00+0000 | April, 10 2013 08:44:00+0000 |          4 |
|      2 | April, 10 2013 08:40:00+0000 | April, 10 2013 08:42:00+0000 |          2 |
|      1 | April, 10 2013 09:40:00+0000 | April, 10 2013 09:42:00+0000 |          2 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff29f/31)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Table1 table
    ([RuleID] int, [TimeStamp] smalldatetime)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([RuleID], [TimeStamp])
VALUES
    (1, '2013-04-10 08:40'),
    (1, '2013-04-10 08:42'),
    (1, '2013-04-10 08:44'),
    (2, '2013-04-10 08:40'),
    (2, '2013-04-10 08:42'),
    (1, '2013-04-10 09:40'),
    (1, '2013-04-10 09:42')
;

select distinct t1.RuleID, t1.Timestamp EarliestTimeStamp,a.LatestTimeStamp, datediff(minute, t1.Timestamp, a.LatestTimeStamp) DurationInMins 
from @Table1 t1
outer apply
(select min(timestamp) LatestTimeStamp from @Table1 t2 
where t1.timestamp <= timestamp and t1.ruleid = ruleid and not exists (select 1 from @table1 where t1.ruleid = ruleid and timestamp > t1.timestamp and timestamp > t2.timestamp and timestamp <= dateadd(minute, 2, t2.timestamp)))a
where not exists(select 1 from @Table1 where timestamp < t1.timestamp and timestamp >= dateadd(minute,-2,t1.timestamp)
and t1.RuleId = RuleId)
```